# Is this a trivial case of the Morse lemma?

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-writing, morse-theory

Say we have a $C^{\infty}$ function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and a point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x_0) = 0$ but $f''(x_0) \not= 0$.

Then does the [Morse lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory#Morse_lemma) guarantee us that there exists a $C^{\infty}$ re-parametrization of the real line, call it $\xi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that, for all points in the open interval $(x_0 - \varepsilon, x_0 + \varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$, $$(f \circ \xi)(x) = f(x_0) \pm (\xi(x))^2 \quad \text{and} \quad \xi(x_0) = 0 \quad ? $$

**Uncertainties:**
**1.** Are we guaranteed a re-parametrization that is defined on the entire real line (perhaps by composing with another re-parametrization)? Or can we only assume that $\xi$ is defined on $(x_0 - \varepsilon, x_0 + \varepsilon)$? (E.g. perhaps because $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0 - \varepsilon} \xi(x) = + \infty, \lim\limits_{x \to x_0 + \varepsilon} \xi_x = -\infty$, and this can't be fixed by applying another re-parametrization while still satisfying the conclusions of the Morse Lemma.)

**2.** Are the conditions given sufficient to guarantee that $f$ is a Morse function, and that the hypotheses of the theorem are satisfied? Are they sufficient at least to guarantee that $f$ is a Morse function when restricted to a sub-manifold which is an open interval about $x_0$?

**3.** Can this trivial/special/degenerate case also be proved using Taylor's theorem? I.e., do we even need to assume that $f$ is $C^{\infty}$, or can we just use Taylor's theorem and assume it is $C^2$?

**Note:** There is a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350019/proof-of-the-morse-lemma-in-dimension-1). That question is about the proof of the result, whereas my question is more about what the correct statement is (in an even more special case). In particular, I am still not entirely comfortable with changes of coordinates, e.g. identifying abuses of notation.

That is why I try to make explicit the change of coordinates as yet another function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and why I try to choose the simplest possible 1-dimensional manifolds, $\mathbb{R}$ or an open subinterval.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349288/lemma-of-morse-in-dimension-1?rq=1  but here I am trying to stick with $\mathbb{R}$ as a 1-dimensional manifold, e.g. a statement of a special case of the lemma I could explain to someone who only completed one semester of introductory calculus, and has no idea what a manifold is. Anyway, if you think this question should be closed, then vote to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The parametrization is certainly local, e.g if $f'(y)$ vanishes then $y \notin (x_0- \varepsilon, x_0 + \varepsilon)$, comparing derivatives.

2) $f$ will be locally a Morse function but it can have degenerate critical points outside $x$, again. So really, your statement as the Morse lemma are local statements.

3) I think you need at least $C^3$, for example imagine a function such that $f''(x_n) = 0$ for some sequence $x_n \to x_0$ and $f''(x_0) \neq 0$. Such function should exists and one can't apply Morse lemma here.